# How can I make my design adapt to portrait and landscape orientation?

Tags: android

How can I make my design adapt to landscape orientation.

in portrait orientation, I designed it like this:

[image]

In landscape orientation it looks like this:

[image]

This is my code

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/bt_ingresar"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="36dp"
    android:text="@string/ingresar_usuario"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.498"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/et_clave" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/bt_registrar"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="36dp"
    android:text="@string/registrar_usuario"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.498"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/bt_ingresar" />
```

Comment: Please don't tag questions with the android-studio tag just because you use it: the Android Studio tag should **only** be used when you have questions about the IDE itself, and not any code you write (or want to write) in it. See [when is it appropriate to remove an IDE tag](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/315196/6296561), [How do I avoid misusing tags?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/354427/6296561), and [the tagging guide](/help/tagging). Use [android] or other relevant tags instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the case is your screen is simply not large enough to show the whole content. Android does not add the scroll functionality if the content is larger then the screen. If this is the case wrap all your views in a ScrollView so that the buttons could be visible after scrolling. Like this:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
          android:orientation="vertical"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:padding="4dp"> 

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <!-- Putt all your view here -->

        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: hello friend, I have a new problem, I don't know how to change the width and apply constraint to the buttons, sorry I'm a beginner

Comment: android:layout_width="100dp" try this to have you desire width.  Also please accept the answer as I solved the problem.